# Run a .exe from java and move on

Tags: java, batch-file, processbuilder

I want to programmatically run a .exe program if it is not running yet.
For the moment i use a process builder to launch a .bat from java. The batch file runs the .exe after checking if it is running.
The problem is that java won't move on until the user closes the .exe program. How can I solve this?

Java code :

```
try {
        ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("open.bat");
        final Process process = builder.start();
        InputStream is = process.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
        while ((br.readLine()) != null) {
        }
        System.out.println("command line terminated");
    } catch (Exception err) {
        err.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("error  ");
    }
```

Batch code : (open.bat)

```
tasklist | find "illustrator.exe"
if errorlevel 1 start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Adobe Illustrator CS6\Support Files\Contents\Windows\illustrator.exe"
```

Comment: create a new Thread?

Comment: Move the `while ((br.readLine()) != null) {` to another thread, allow it consume the results quietly, this will allow the rest of the code, remember, IO tends to be blocking and so are loops ;)

Comment: do you get the "command line terminated" output ??distroy your process

Comment: This is odd; `start` should return immediately. When you print the lines you read from the program, does it say anything?

Comment: @MadProgrammer That *shouldn't* be necessary here, right? As `start` should start `illustrator.exe` detached and theoretically the batch file shouldn't be waiting at all for the program it runs to end.

Comment: @MadProgrammer I would like to avoid any multithreading in my Java program.

Comment: @JasonC Havn't tested it, but even so, you should be consuming the output of the batch file (if any), as sometimes, this prevents the process from closing...

Comment: @Audrey What you would like to do and what you might need to do are two different things ;)

Comment: @Audrey Add `builder.redirectErrorStream(true);` just prior to `.start()` to make sure you're handling its stderr output as well. Does that solve your issue?

Comment: @whiletrue No, the "command line terminated" doesn't display unless the user closes illustrator

Comment: @JasonC I did. There's seems to be no error stream to display

Comment: @Audrey You tried with `redirectErrorStream`?

Comment: @JasonC Yes. I just did.

Comment: @Audrey When you run your .bat file directly from a command prompt, does it exit right away, or does it way for illustrator to be closed?

Comment: Additionnal information : If i run the batch file from windows explorer it moves on without waiting.

Comment: Second, batch file runs fine from the command line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated**

Using...

```
start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Adobe Illustrator CS4\Support Files\Contents\Windows\illustrator.exe"
```

As the `open.bat` batch file and using...

```
try {
    ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("open.bat");
    builder.redirectError();
    builder.inheritIO();
    final Process process = builder.start();
    final InputStream is = process.getInputStream();
    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
    String text = null;
    while ((text = br.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(text);
    }

    System.out.println("command line terminated");
    System.out.println("Exited with " + process.waitFor());
} catch (Exception err) {
    err.printStackTrace();
    System.out.println("error  ");
}
```

I can get the batch file to run and terminate and still have Illustrator load and run.

The primary addition is the call to `ProcessBuilder#inheritIO`, which does some magic I'm not aware of, but seems to allow the batch file to terminate...

From the [JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#inheritIO())

> This gives behavior equivalent to most operating system command interpreters, or the standard C library function system().

Comment: @Audrey Yea, that was a fun roller coaster ride of "I don't know why this works, but it does, so don't think about too long or it might stop" ... same old, same old at the office than ;)

Comment: From the API : 

    pb.inheritIO()
 
behaves in exactly the same way as the invocation 
 
     pb.redirectInput(Redirect.INHERIT)
   .redirectOutput(Redirect.INHERIT)
   .redirectError(Redirect.INHERIT)

Comment: Fascinating. I'd love to investigate more deeply when I have a chance. Must be something odd about the way `start` sets up its standard streams. Good work getting it to work.

Comment: @Audrey Just out of curiosity, if you have the chance, does your original version work if you change the command in the batch file to `cmd /C start ...`?

Comment: @JasonC I'm about 90% sure it didn't work for me, but I did so many weird things I could be wrong...